# Find value located in the last record using VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

I know this has probably been asked thousands of times before, but I seem to be having trouble finding an existing question that addresses this question in a wy I can understand.

My question in how can I access a value located in the last record of a table? For example, if this is my table:

```
personID personName personNumber
1        Sally      PR32
2        Emily      PR33
3        Joseph     PR34
```

I want to access the value "PR34" (and then be able to manipulate it if possible). I know how to find the last record with Dmax, but I'm struggling to figure out how to find a value within it. I'm ultimately trying to take the value, parse the string down to just the numbers, and increment it by one (and then append the letters back on).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in a query as well:

```
UPDATE T 
SET T.personNumber = "PR" & CLng(Replace([personNumber], "PR", "")) + 1
WHERE (((T.personID)=(SELECT Max(personID) FROM T)));
```

Where T is the name of your Table.

Comment: This looks promising, but it is giving me a type conversion error. Do I need to specify that T.personNumber would be a string or something?

Comment: Hmm... No errors on my machine. Do you run it as a query directly or through VBA?

Comment: Actually, it was right the first time. Upon further inspection I realized I had provided a poor example of my situation in the question. My actual field had a dash in it (MFT534-2017) and I had forgot to account for that. When I took that out, this code works well. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you're in the DLookUp/DMax workflow, you can just use the following:

This gives you the ID, you already figured this out:

```
DMax("PersonID", "MyTable")
```

Then lookup the associated personNumber with that ID:

```
DLookUp("personNumber", "MyTable", "personID = " & DMax("PersonID", "MyTable"))
```

But if you want to manipulate it (or just be more efficient), using a recordset is the way to go:

```
'Create a recordset
Dim rs As Recordset
'Query the last value, get the personNumber
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT TOP 1 personNumber FROM MyTable ORDER BY personID DESC")
'Open it up for editing
rs.Edit
'Increment the number by 1
rs.Fields("personNumber").Value = Left(rs.Fields("personNumber").Value, 2) & CInt(Mid(rs.Fields("personNumber").Value, 3, Len(rs.Fields("personNumber").Value) - 2)) + 1
'Update the recordset
rs.Update
```